# Don't have an option for making Azure AD app multitenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to turn on the multi tenant feature in Azure AD. But i can't see an option for that in my application's configure tab. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Is it a client application or a web application?

Comment: @GauravMantri It's a web application.

Comment: Is your application in the default active directory of your subscription, and you don't have the permission to view or add user in the default directory?